# How to change Text Box to Select Box in Opencart 3?

Tags: php, opencart, opencart-3

When I upload product in Opencart-3 and search Categories in Links > Categories then the Categories will search and show as a Drop Down but Searching will take a lot of time. then what I need to do? I am looking to make it "Select Box".
So how to convert this text box to select box? I think select will not search and show the categories faster.

You can check the below image so that you can get my point:-
[image: https://i.ibb.co/0JpKF5Q/opencart.jpg]

Comment: you should edit template product_form.twig and corresponding controller file product.php

Comment: but what do i need to change? what code?

Comment: Make sure your database tables are indexed: https://www.antropy.co.uk/blog/opencart-1-5-site-search-very-slow/